# Можно ли делать логические операторы в поиске объекта в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-events

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, можно ли делать логические операторы в поиске объекта в jquery

Вот сам код, пример:

```
$('.block_from input.form_ajax || select.form_ajax').click(function()
{
     //my code
});
```

То есть в родителе .block_from нужно взять или input.form_ajax либо же select.form_ajax в зависимости от клика ?

Или нужно хардкодить и писать больше кода ? А это вроде не дефис jquery.

Comment: В качестве разделителя используется `,` - запятая.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.block_from input.form_ajax, .block_from select.form_ajax')...

$('.block_from').find('input.form_ajax, select.form_ajax')...

$('input.form_ajax, select.form_ajax', $('.block_from'))...
```